# JIRA java API - how to get list of values for custom field

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

With JIRA JAVA API (jira-rest-java-client-core), I'm trying to set custom field value. During creation of issue I can set custom field

```
Field myField = ...
new IssueInputBuilder().setFieldValue(myField.getId(), <value ??>)
```

But I don't know what should be the value. I mean I don't know how I can obtain list of available values. If I go to the web page I see list of values: Val1, Val2 etc. But how I can obtain them via API?

Thanks
Bartek